# Function returning the same output values for diferent parameters - python 3.8

Tags: python, arrays, function, module

i am trying to build a code that plot gauss distributions for diferent parameteres, but i am getting something wrong. I have wrote this code:

```
from numpy import zeros,empty,array,loadtxt,dot
import numpy as np
from math import log,exp,sin,cos,sqrt,pi,e,sqrt
from pylab import plot,show,ylim,ylabel,xlabel

n=10

#definindo os vetores posição e os vetores f que irão armazenar o valor da função no ponto.

f= zeros(n+1,float)
f1=zeros(n+1,float) 
f2= zeros(n+1,float)
f3= zeros(n+1,float)
x= zeros(n+1,float)

    
#Definindo a função gaussiana
    

def gauss(xi,xf,sig,a):
    step=(xf-xi)/n
    for k in range(n+1):
        f[k]=(1.0/(sqrt(2*pi)*sig))*exp((-(xi+step*k-a)**2)/(2*sig**2))     
        x[k]=xi+step*k
    print(f)
    return f



# A partir de agora iremos chamar a função gauss três vezes para plotar a função para diferentes valores dos parametros

f1=gauss(-5,5,5,0)

f2=gauss(-5,5,2,0)


plot(x,f1)
plot(x,f2)
show()
```

But when i plot the functions f1 and f2, i get the exact same graph.

Comment: In ```def gauss``` : ```*sig /sig = 1``` So ```sig``` has no influence on the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an aliasing problem with having your `f` and `x` lists be global. With the way you have it setup when you call `plot(x, f2)` you're essentially calling `plot(x, f)` because of the way you modify `f` in `guass`.

You can see this by running:

```py
print('F1: ', f1)
f1 = gauss(-5, 5, 5, 0)
print('F1: ', f1)
print('F == F1: ', np.array_equal(f, f1))
f2 = gauss(-5, 5, 2, 0)
print('F1: ', f1)
print('F == F1: ', np.array_equal(f, f1))
print('F2 == F1: ', np.array_equal(f2, f1))
print('F2 == F: ', np.array_equal(f2, f))
```

Which produces

```py
F1:  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
F1:  [0.04839414 0.05793831 0.06664492 0.07365403 0.07820854 0.07978846
 0.07820854 0.07365403 0.06664492 0.05793831 0.04839414]
F == F1:  True
F1:  [0.00876415 0.02699548 0.0647588  0.12098536 0.17603266 0.19947114
 0.17603266 0.12098536 0.0647588  0.02699548 0.00876415]
F == F1:  True
F2 == F1:  True
F2 == F:  True
```

---

By moving `f` and `x` to be initialized in your `guass` function and returning both, you should be getting the type of results you were expecting.

```py
from math import exp, pi, sqrt

from numpy import zeros
from pylab import plot, show

n = 10


def gauss(xi, xf, sig, a):
    step = (xf - xi) / n
    f = zeros(n + 1, float)
    x = zeros(n + 1, float)
    for k in range(n + 1):
        f[k] = (1.0 / (sqrt(2 * pi) * sig)) * exp((-(xi + step * k - a) ** 2) / (2 * sig ** 2))
        x[k] = xi + step * k
    return x, f


x1, f1 = gauss(-5, 5, 5, 0)
x2, f2 = gauss(-5, 5, 2, 0)

plot(x1, f1)
show()
plot(x1, f2)
show()
```